# What dependencies to create and use SOAP Web Services should I add to the POM if I am working with Widfly 26.1.1, JDK 11 and JEE 8?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, wildfly, java-ee-8

I'm trying to create SOAP Web Services with Wildfly 26.1.1, JDK 11 and JEE 8 on Apache NetBeans 12.6, and I get this error (I had previously created NetBeans 8.2 with JEE 7 without problem):

```
Deploying on WildFly Application Server
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
Undeploying ...
Initial deploying WebServicesSOAP to D:\Applications Servers\wildfly-26.1.1\wildfly-26.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments\webServicesSOAP-1.0.war
Completed initial distribution of WebServicesSOAP
Deploying D:\Applications Servers\wildfly-26.1.1\wildfly-26.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments\webServicesSOAP-1.0.war
"{
    \"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services\" => {\"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"webServicesSOAP-1.0.war\\\".INSTALL\" => \"WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \\\"webServicesSOAP-1.0.war\\\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.wsf.spi.WSFException: JBWS024109: Could not get WSDL contract for endpoint com.sun.xml.ws.tx.coord.v11.endpoint.RegistrationPortImpl at /wsdls/wsc11/wstx-wscoor-1.1-wsdl-200702.wsdl\"},
    \"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:\" => [
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"webServicesSOAP-1.0.war\\\".WeldStartService\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"webServicesSOAP-1.0.war\\\".beanmanager\"
    ],
    \"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies\" => [
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"webServicesSOAP-1.0.war\\\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"webServicesSOAP-1.0.war\\\".beanmanager, jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"webServicesSOAP-1.0.war\\\".WeldStartService]\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"webServicesSOAP-1.0.war\\\".batch.artifact.factory is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"webServicesSOAP-1.0.war\\\".beanmanager]\"
    ]
}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Wildfly BOM (aka "Bill Of Materials") and include the appropriate artifact in your pom as dependency:

For WF 26:

https://github.com/wildfly/boms/tree/26.x

This will ensure your app will be using the exact same version for libs (**both for api and impl**) that are present in WF stack (for instance Jackson)

As an alternative, you can also directly import the JEE 8 api (with provided scope):

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But then you are only in sync with the **API**